# Convert struct field to unsigned char string

Tags: c, struct

I'm on an embedded system so do not have access to a most of the standard library. I have a `struct` which contains char values.

I have a simple `print` function which simply outputs an unsigned char string to an attached screen. It does not support format specifiers like `printf` does.

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct my_options{
    char test;
} my_options;
```

And this is where I'm trying to output the value:

```
 struct my_options options;
 print(options.test);  //Here I get "implicit conversion of int to ptr"
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I meant to type print, sorry.

Comment: What does your `print` function look like then? Can you show it here?

Comment: Nobody can answer this question, since there exists no standard function called `print`. Every answer below is just speculation, most of them likely got fooled by the mentioning of `puts`. Please show the function prototype of `print`

Comment: If `options.test` had the value of 64, would you want to see "@", "64" or something else printed?

Answer (score 3):

Create a char array to hold your char and then print it:

```
char wrapper[2];
wrapper[0] = options.test;
wrapper[1] = '\0';
print(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary 2-character long string that has the character to print, and then the terminator. Then pass that string to your `print()` function:

```
void print_options(const struct my_options *opt)
{
  char tmp[] = { opt->test, '\0' };
  print(tmp);
}
```

Comment: That `'\0'` isn't required, though if you write `char tmpo[2] = {opt->test};`, is it?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Not required, but good programming practice. `tmp[] = {opt->test, '\0'}` tells the reader "I know what I'm doing", while `tmpo[2] = {opt->test};` tells the reader that "I might know what I'm doing, or I might be clueless and just got lucky by accident, since the C language guarantees a zero-out on the second item in the array". It's called self-documenting code.

Comment: @Lundin: Point taken, I'd call the temp var `wrapper[2]`, which basically is the same type of self-documenting code, but perhaps explicitly writing the `\0` leaves even less room for doubt.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I agree on using the explicit `[2]`.

Comment: @Lundin: It would seem, then, that we agree on many things :-P. I'll edit my answer to make the `\0` explicit, too. Self-documenting code is something I still need to work on

Answer (score 1):

your member `test` if of the type `char`, where the `print` function expects an argument of the type `const char *` (assuming the `const` bit here, but that's what I'd expect, this as an asside). Passing the address of `test` then would *seem* like the appropriate solution, but is it?

**No**, of course it isn't. There is no *absolute* guarantee that the next byte after `test` will be `'\0'` (a string terminating char). What you, then, ought to do is create a wrapper string:

```
char char_wrapper[2] = {};//initializes according to standard
//but as Lundin pointed out, self-documenting code is important:
char_wrapper[0] = options.test;?
char_wrapper[1] = '\0';//explicit, so it's clear what this code does
print(char_wrapper);
```

That should work just fine.
You can, of course, write this as a one-liner:

```
char char_wrapper[2] = {options.test, '\0'};//same as before, only in 1 statement
print(char_wrapper);//print "string"
```

That should do it, really. You don't even have to explicitly write the terminating char, since the standard specifically states:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
>   enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

***6.7.8 Initialization*** [cf p. 138, semantics, point 14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Be that as it may, I'd still prefer to browse the web, or just set about writing your own minor implementation of `printf` so you can use format specifiers. Heck, it's one of the first exercises in the K&R book, and there's tons of solutions floating about on the net. check those out, and adapt them to your specific needs.
Or, perhaps define `print` to accept a `size_t` argument, to specify how many chars you want to pass to the output stream. and call it like so `print(options.test, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

`print` is looking for a `char*`. You are passing an  `char` which can also be represented as an `int`. Thus, the function is trying to implicitly convert an `int` to a pointer as it is telling you.

```
char ptr[2];
ptr[0] = options.test;
ptr[1] = '\0';
```

Would wrap the `char` into a `char` array, which in C will decay into a pointer when you pass it to a function.

Comment: Your first suggestion isn't safe, and doesn't require you to allocate the pointer in the first place: `char *pChar = &options.test;` would do fine, but then (as I stated in my answer), there is no guarantee that `print` will encounter a null-terminating char. your suggestion is better, but still relies on `malloc`, why not simply: `char wrapper[2] = {options.test, '\0'};`? Use stack memory whenever you can, I'd say

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: "However, bear in mind that pChar is a pointer to the char and will only be valid while `options.test` is in scope. That means that you can't return pChar from a function and expect it to work; it will be pointing to some part of the heap and you can't expect that to stay valid."

Comment: That's not what I'm saying... what I'm hinting at is, say, the memory looks like this: `fooXbar\0`, and `options.test` happens to be that `X` char, passing a pointer to that address in memory would have `print` assume that it needs to print `Xbar\0`<-- since it only encounters a terminating zero char after `r`, not after `X`. That's not what the OP wants. Besides: OP doesn't have access to the `stdlib` (as he explicitly stated in his question), that implies: no access to `malloc`, too. That, and `sizeof(char)` is redundant: `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1

Comment: Where did `puts` come from? Also, dynamic allocation is most often not an option on embedded systems. Also, why would you dynamically allocate 2 bytes when you can just declare a 2 byte array on the stack?

Comment: @Lundin: Originally it said puts... the edit doesn't show because I answered within the first 5 minutes.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I can see your point. I will edit. But I really don't know what the `print` function looks like.

Comment: @GIJoe: it's a _"home-brew"_ function the OP uses for his system. That's why I just edited my answer, saying the OP might want to consider working on that `print` function to allow for format specifiers, or pass a `size_t` argument (for the nr of chars). Anyway: will check your edit, but just so you know, the -1 wasn't mine :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Understood. I just saw the edit changing `puts` to `print`. But looking at the source for `puts`, it uses `strlen`, which would need the null-terminating char so I can see how my original solution had a pitfall.

Comment: +1: arrays decaying into pointers is still not basic knowledge to some, good of you to add that to your answer